# Does rank< U > match rank< U [N] >?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

The following code is from the wonderful lecgture by Walter E Brown.

I have several quesions about this code.

(1) Does `rank< U >` match `rank< U [N] >` ?

(2) How is recursion performed?

Thanks!

```
#include <cstddef>  // size_t
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template< typename T >
struct rank 
{ 
  static constexpr size_t value = 0u; 
};


template< typename U, size_t N >
struct rank< U[N] > 
{ 
  static constexpr size_t value = 1u + rank< U >::value; // This confuses me.
};


template< typename U >
struct rank< U[] > 
{ 
  static constexpr size_t value = 1u + rank< U >::value; 
};


int main() {
  using array_t1 = int[10][20][30];

  cout << rank< array_t1 >::value << endl;

}
```

Comment: `rank<int[10][20]>` matches `rank<U[N]>` with `U=int[10]` and `N=20`, resulting to
 `rank<int[10][20]>::value == 1u + rank<int[10]>::value`.

Comment: Recursion takes place at compile time : At first rank<U[N]> is compiled with U = int[10][20] and N=30, then rank<int[10],20> and then rank<U[]> is compiled increasing value one more time.

Comment: @Jarod42 and Pepijn Kramer Thanks. Very clear explanations! :)